# Using increased/decreased variables in django templates

Tags: django, templates

Maybe it's a little bit stupid question, but I didn't find an answer. Is there any way to use increased/decreased variables in django templates?

e.g.`{{ some_variable + 1 }}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a built-in [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter:

```
{{ some_variable|add:"1" }}
```

Comment: that does not seem to set the variable. For example, if you initialize some_variable to 1, your suggestion will always return 2

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by using a django template filter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

```
def inc(value):
    return value+1
```

and then:

```
{{ some_variable|inc }}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately some_variable does not get incremented

Answer (score 1):

Inside for loop use forloop.counter that will automatically increase the counter till the records.

```
{% for a in object_list %}
{{ forloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```